# Route to home page with page refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using react,redux and next.js .

I have a USER component loaded with user data.In this component,I have logout button along with user data. Here, userdata route and home route are on same location.
When i click on logout, I am re-setting the store state and replacing the route with Router.replace('/').

After logout, its resetting the store state. But, page is not refreshed because userdata route and home route ('/') are on same location. How to refresh the page ? Any possible option without using Router.reload() ?

Comment: If it is the same route, resetting the store state should be enough… How do you choose the component to render when the main route is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`window.location.reload()`

It will help you to reload whole page by initializing the states.
Hope, it'll help you.